# Web scraping frame within htm;

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I am new to web scraping. I am trying to scrape the linked information in https://www.harris.com/careers/jobs for each job position. The information is contained within the following XPath: //*[@id="frmJobs"]. I am using the Chrome "Scraper" plugin. The plugin is not able to select the frame using all the selectors available. I am wondering if there is an easy way to create a sitemap that will get inside the frame and extract all linked information. Please let me know if this is at all possible.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I tried Octoparse, the web scraping tool to extract the frame data and I got all the information I want. I enter "public health" for example in the text box to search the jobs and extract those results. I upload the .otd file [that is the configuration rule using Octoparse to extract the jobs of public health](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fhfhq9hjs3vt5m7/Harris_Copy.otd?dl=0).  [Results of extracting the jobs of public health are shown below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or534.png)